# Unable to install FlatPak (Linux - Monodevelop)

Tags: linux, mono, monodevelop, apt-get, flatpak

I was trying to install FlatPak through apt-get, then I realised that it is not in the packages database, so as suggested in their website (http://flatpak.org/getting/) I added the repository:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexlarsson/flatpak
```

however, the command generated an error and I don't know what to do next:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/linuxmint/mintSources/mintSources.py", line 1258, in <module>
codename = config_parser.get("general", "base_codename")
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ConfigParser.py", line 330, in get
raise NoSectionError(section)
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'general'
```

The purpose of this was to upgrade MonoDevelop, because I've version 5.1, and now version 6.1 is available, but it seems that new versions won't be available through the repo anymore. This is the reason I was trying to download from their website, but it uses a FlatPak package

I would appreciate any suggestion or tip of the next step to follow.

Thank you very much.

Comment: https://blog.lextudio.com/the-success-of-running-monodevelop-7-on-linux-a55f1469b1d1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To upgrade MonoDevelop from 5.1, I to had problems with FlatPak.
My problem was that FlatPak is not compatible with the linux I was using at the time, Ubuntu 14.04.

For the MonoDevelop upgrade I end up forgetting about FlatPak, downloaded the MonoDevelop source and compiled it myself.
http://www.monodevelop.com/developers/building-monodevelop/

I am now running MonoDevelop 7.2

Comment: You don't need to compile from source, https://blog.lextudio.com/the-success-of-running-monodevelop-7-on-linux-a55f1469b1d1

Comment: Thanks, I think that is the source of the issue. I do also use v14.04